# Creating feed files by writing unix shell scripts

Tags: unix, shell, scripting

I don't know how to create a text feed files using UNIX shell scripts?

Can you please give me the sample for the same.

Comment: You need to provide much more detail particularly what type of feed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are going to create RSS feeds. Search the web for how to create RSS feeds. There are many examples, such as [this](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/465.cfm) and [this](http://searchenginewatch.com/2175271) and many more. the basic idea is to echo the information to a file,

eg

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' >> feeds.txt
```

there are also feed tools such as [rsstool](http://rsstool.berlios.de/) to make creation easy. I have not used it, but you can have a look